# Deploying webapp with maven-wildfly plugin, deploy war under deployment directory

Tags: java, maven, deployment, wildfly-8

I am using [wildfly-maven-plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/index.html) for deploying webapp to **Wildfly 8.1**. Using `wildfly:deploy` goal, and webapp get deployed somewhere in wildfly directory. Following are my pom.xml and server.log.

```
<build>
        <plugins>             
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.Final</version> // Also tried latest one.
                <configuration>
                    <jbossHome>/home/me/jboss/</jbossHome>
                    <server-args>
                        <server-arg>-Djboss.server.base.dir=/home/me/jboss/standalone/</server-arg>
                        <server-arg>-b=0.0.0.0</server-arg>
                    </server-args>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

My small part of **server.log**

```
13:55:22,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
13:55:22,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
13:55:22,672 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
13:55:22,672 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" started in 60324ms - Started 668 of 722 services (93 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

But my `/standalone/deployment/` directory is blank, also no hidden files. So where this thing get deployed !! And also deleted all war files from target and .m2 directory.

Webapp entry in **standalone.xml**

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" runtime-name="MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
            <content sha1="c9f1534c910dacdf6789ed585ae17cef73cfbe44"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

So I need to deploy war file under `/standalone/deployments/` directory.

Comment: Have you tried navigating to localhost:8080 to see if the web app is online? You can also search you computer for "MyApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT" and it should find it for you?

Comment: Alternatively, you can right click the project and export it to a war file and choose where you want it to be placed and then manually place it inside the deployments folder

Comment: @Alan Yes app is working perfectly smoothly. I also `grep` throughout my /home/. But no luck. Found only in server.log and standalone.xml !!

Comment: @Alan I can do manual things. But I need automated things!!

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Eclipse, correct? Go to Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment > Click on Wildfly > Edit and check the home directory

Comment: @Alan Yes I m using eclipse for just development, not building app with it. I m building app using maven cli.

Answer (score 3):

The Maven WildFly Plugin deploys the application through the administration interface (by default running on port 9990). The deployment always goes into the directory standalone/tmp.

The alternative for deployment to /standalone/deployments/ directory is copying the application war directly to it.

Comment: So, there is no way to direct deploy war under /standalone/deployments directory !!!

Answer (score 1):

To deploy your application under standalone directory, you need to copy it to that path. The configuration can be done from pom.xml as below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-war</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>\home\me\jboss\standalone\deployments</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```